# Default access modifier for class and variable in C#?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

What is default access modifier for Class and for Variable in C#?

**For Class, there are two type of Access modifier: Pulic/ Internal. And Internal by Default?
For Variable, there are four type of Access modifier: Public/Internal/Protected/Private. And Private by Default?**

In Java, Public is the Default Access modifier. But I really do not know what is exactly in C#?

Comment: You seem to have answered yourself in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's funny what you can find by using google. For example [the MSDN page about classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0b0thckt.aspx). It states:

> Classes are internal by default.

And later:

> Types declared inside a class without an access modifier default to private

Comment: Can we use Public for variable inside a class?

Comment: @VyClarks It's syntactically possible. It's bad style though. It breaks encapsulation. If you need something to be public, make it a property or method.

Answer (score 1):

The default is internal for class and private for class members, but I recommend declaring it  explicitly

Comment: Can we use public for variable inside a class?